# Remove Dataframes from List of Dataframes based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a script that creates a list of dataframes to concatenate. Before concatenation, I am checking a certain column in each dataframe for the presence of a '1' binary flag. If there is not a one, I want to delete the dataframe from the list of dataframes. I am having trouble because I am not sure how to properly index the list to remove the dataframe. I recreated the problem with this code.

```
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]} 
data2 = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]} 

# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

dflist = [df, df2, df3, df4]


for frame in dflist:
        vals = frame["Name"].values
        if 'krish' not in vals:
             dflist.remove(frame)
```

But

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I also tried enumerating the list and deleting based off dflist[i], but that changes the index if something is deleted so subsequently the wrong frames will be removed.

What is the proper way to remove dataframes from a list of df's based on condition? Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of removing items from a list while iterating, which is generally a bad practice, use a list comprehension to generate a new list with the dataframes of interest:

```
[i for i in dflist if 'krish' not in i['Name'].values]

  Name  Age
 0  Tom   20
 1  Tom   21
 2  Tom   19
 3  Tom   18,   Name  Age
 0  Tom   20
 1  Tom   21
 2  Tom   19
 3  Tom   18]
```

---

If the dataframes are very large, here's a *safe* way to remove the unwanted dataframes from the original list:

```
ix = []
for i, frame in enumerate(dflist):
        vals = frame["Name"]
        if not vals.isin(['krish']).any():
             ix.append(i)

# sort the indices of dataframes to drop
# by starting from higher to lower indices you're guaranteed
# that the indices on the dataframe will remain unmodified while deleting
for i in sorted(ix, reverse=True):
    del dflist[i]
```

Comment: How about the dataframe in list is huge , and memory can not hold two of them

Comment: In that case the way to go would be iterating over the list and finding the indices I guess @WeNYoBen will clarify anyway

Comment: yea definitely more pythonic/efficient, how would this be used to delete the dataframes?

Comment: Are the dataframes too large? @johnny1995 otherwise you cna just create the new list and delete `dflist`

Comment: reversing the order of the index to delete fixed the problem i was having, i didnt think of that! thank you!

Comment: Also , you first list conversion output the opposite :-) vote for u too

Answer (score 2):

You should using `del` from `index` part rather than using `remove`

```
l=[]
for index,frame in enumerate(dflist):
        vals = frame["Name"].values
        if 'krish' not in vals:
             l.append(index)
for x in sorted(l, reverse=True):
    del dflist[x]
```

Comment: I tried that, but deleting changes the length of the list so the index changes. i.e. if dflist[1] is deleted frame 3 is now dflist[1]

Comment: i tried that exact code before posting lol, it deletes the wrong frame because after the first delete the index is altered.